# APIGEE querying data that DOESN'T match condition

Tags: apigee

I need to fetch from BaaS data store all records that doesn't match condition

I use query string like:

```
https://api.usergrid.com/<org>/<app>/<collection>?ql=location within 10 of 30.494697,50.463509 and Partnership eq 'Reject'
```

that works right (i don't url encode string after ql).

But any attempt to put "not" in this query cause "The query cannot be parsed".
Also i try to use <>, !=, NE, and some variation of "not"

How to configure query to fetch all records in the range but Partnership NOT Equal 'Reject' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not operations are supported, but are not performant because it requires a full scan.  When coupled with a geolocation call, it could be quite slow.  We are working on improving this in the Usergrid core.

Having said that, in general, it is much better to inverse the call if possible.  For example, instead of adding the property when the case is true, always write the property to every new entity (even when false), then edit the property when the case is true.

Instead of doing this:

POST 
{
  'name':'fred'
}

PUT
{
  'name':'fred'
  'had_cactus_cooler':true
}

Do this:
POST
{
  'name':'fred'
  'had_cactus_cooler':'no'
}

PUT
{
  'name':'fred'
  'had_cactus_cooler':'yes'
}

In general, try to put your data in the way you want to get it out. Since you know upfront that you want to query on whether this property exists, simply add it, but with a negative value.  The update it when the condition becomes true.

Comment: well Thank you for explanation. so i add to all records that has no key "Partnership" in db {"Partnership":"pending"} and now i able to fetch records using positive condition.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this syntax:

```
https://api.usergrid.com/<org>/<app>/<collection>?ql=location within 10 of 30.494697,50.463509 and not Partnership eq 'Reject'
```

Notice that the `not` operator comes before the expression (as indicated in the [docs](http://apigee.com/docs/api-baas/content/supported-query-operators-data-types)).

Comment: Is any way to query data that has no key in json? i.e. Partnership eq null or something like that ?

Comment: @IgorVatsenko not directly no, but you should be able to rig up something using `select * where key contains '*'` maybe?